# R CMD SHLIB to create a DLL from a source .c file which needs an external library (on Windows x64)

Tags: c, r, compilation, static-libraries

First things first, I am very new to C programming and the whole idea of compilation, so I would really appreciate some very straightforward and step-by-step guidance on this.

Here is my problem: I am trying to write some C code that I can dyn.load into R to speed up my R task. My C code would involve some very complex matrix operation that is only available in an external library with the header file "matrix.h" and the static library file "matrix.lib". It would also make use of some basic R header files such as "Rdefines.h", etc. The files "matrix.h" and "matrix.lib" are located at `C:\lcc\include` and `C:\lcc\lib`, respectively. Here is a sample test C code:

```
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h> 

void foo(double *cdegree, double *fdegree, int *size) {

  int i; 
  for(i=0; i<*size; i++) {
    cdegree[i] = 5.0/9.0*(fdegree[i]-32.0);
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is simple code converting Fahrenheit to Celsius. Although the test code does not make use of anything in the matrix library, the goal here is to be able to include both the R header files and matrix.h from the external library. If I try `R CMD SHLIB` this C code I get the "no such file or directory" error for trying to include "matrix.h". How can I tell R to compile this with the external library? Everything is done on a Windows 8.1 X64 system.

Comment: Any reason you pass `size` by pointer and not just `int`?

Comment: @Olaf: I believe that's how it works when you `.C()` in R: everything is passed as pointers. This code compiles and works fine if I just remove "matrix.h".

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you will find it much easier if you start exploring `Rcpp`.  Here is a [link](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) to introduce you to Rcpp.  There are many examples to be found throughout the documentation.

f2c.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo(Rcpp::NumericVector fdegree, Rcpp::NumericVector cdegree, int size){

  int i;
  for(i=0; i < size; i++){
    cdegree[i] = 5.0/9.0*(fdegree[i]-32.0);
  }
}
```

R code

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("f2c.cpp")

fdegree <- c(98.6, 212, 32)
cdegree <- c(0,0,0)

foo(fdegree, cdegree, length(fdegree))
cdegree
[1]  37 100   0
```

Naturally this makes some assumptions but it demonstrates how you can quickly use some C code and not fiddle with all the R headers and SHLIB.

Regarding your concern to use some external headers, just simply set the `PKG_CXXFLAGS` environmental variable to the location of your header(s).

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS" = '-I"path/to/headers"')
```

followed by the same compilation.

```
sourceCpp("f2c.cpp")
```

However, it should be noted that if you are doing more than a few of these functions you should build a package with Rcpp and provide an appropriate `Makevars` file.  You can find further information on Rcpp package development [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf).

Comment: OP asks about a C solution. There might be resons he does not use C++.

Comment: @cdeterman: I tried your approach setting  `PKG_CXXFLAGS` to `C:/lcc/include`, but I still got the same "no such file or directory" error if I `#include <matrix.h>`. I even tried to set `PKG_CFLAGS` and then run `R CMD SHLIB`, same result. Seems this is not the way to tell the R compiler where the external header is. Plus, I think I also need to supply the compiler with the location of `matrix.lib`.

Comment: Regarding @Olaf's comment, yes I would prefer a C solution. The reason is I learned C a long time ago, and may not have time now to learn C++. Unless there is a way to make Rcpp compile C code. But still, the issue with the external library is my main problem right now.

Comment: @aenima: Not sure what Rcpp actually is, but as a general warning: do not compile C code with a C++ compiler (at least no non-trivial code). C++ is not superset of C (whoever  tells you different should do a quick search for "c c++ differences" with his prefered search engine or here on SO).

Comment: @aenima I forgot to indicate the -I. See my edit and try again. As for compiling c code. An Rcpp package is designed to use whichever compiler is appropriate. See documentation and existing packages for examples.

Comment: This is getting silly. @cdeterman gives a nice answer utilizing the fact that Rcpp makes compiling / linking / loading from within an R session trivial. Yes, the is technically C++ but if you want to write C style you can (and just ignore sticklers like @Olaf; the difference does not matter in real programming).  Lastly, if OP really wanted to, the older [inline](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/inline/index.html) package also works for real pure C (and even Fortran).  All he needs is documented there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Sure, it really is negligible not to have the classes used in the example when writing C code. How about providing an answer for C then, if the "the difference does not matter in real programming"? Should be easy going

Comment: Charles already provided a nice answer.  If it doesn't suit you, show something better/easier/shorter that still works from R.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful comments. I will look into Rcpp. I did manage to get `R CMD SHLIB` to link to the external header and library by modifying `PKG_CPPFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS` in the `makeconf` file under `Rversion/etc/x64`, but a series of warnings ensue mostly regarding conflicting definitions. I guess that's because `matrix.h` and `matrix.lib` was compiled and distributed by another compiler called `lcc-win` and may not be fully compatible with R compiler (which is essentially `gcc` I presume?).